# Get text of RadAutoCompleteBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, rad-controls

How can I get the text of a RadAutoCompleteBox using RadControls Q1 2013 in C#?

`autoCompleteBox.SelectedItem` returns `"ServerCrafterTelerikWPF.Command"`.

**Edit 1:**
Here's my XAML:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox x:Name="txtboxCommand" ItemsSource="{Binding Commands, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" 
DisplayMemberPath="ACommand"  AutoCompleteMode="Append" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Modern" Margin="280,405,0,0" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" Height="30" KeyDown="txtboxCommand_KeyDown"/>
```

And I don't have any C# code. I just want, when a button is pressed, to get the text that is in the RadAutoCompleteBox.

**Edit 2:**
And here's my `collection`:

```
public class Command
{
    public string ACommand { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// A view model for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Command> Commands { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Commands = new ObservableCollection<Command>()
            {
                new Command() {ACommand = "stop "},
                // Other commands...
                // ...
                // ...
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `XAML` and `Code`.

Comment: you haven't shown us how you get the selected item of the RadAutoCompleteBox control. Please post the code.

Comment: I think I `got` your problem. Problem should be you get the selected item `as a string`. But it `should` be the type of `Command clas`s. (Actually it should be the type of a `collection of Command` class because the RadAutoCompleteBox can have `multiple selected items`.) Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take it from the `SelectedItem` property. Cast it to your class and then get it from `MyClass.ACommand`

And I suggest binding `SelectedItem` with `Mode=TwoWay` in your ViewModel can help a lot.

Just add a Member to ViewModel which is implementing Command like:

```
private Command _SelectedItem;

public Command SelectedItem 
{ 
   //get set with INotifyPropertyChanged 
}
```

Then from the xaml: Bind RadAutoCompleteBox's SelectedItem Property like:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm new to C# and I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

Comment: I've changed my answer to explain with more detail.

Comment: **yes. This is the answer.** Here you assumed that there is only `one selected item`. But actually `multiple items can be seleceted` in the RadAutoCompleteBox control. So Instead of using `Command` use `ObservableCollection<Command>` to bind the `SelectedItems` (plural of SelectedItem) property of the control.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the problem.

Yes. I had the `same problem`. And I `found` the problem and the answer too.

I got the problem **because of using of type string** for the selected item in my view model.

```cs
private string selectedCommand;

public string SelectedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return selectedCommand;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCommand");
    }
}
```

Use the **type as Command class** and your problem will be solved.

```cs
private Command selectedCommand;

public Command SelectedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return selectedCommand;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCommand");
    }
}
```

`Bind` the `SelectedItem` property of the `RadAutoCompleteBox` in the `XAML`

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox 
            x:Name="txtboxCommand" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Commands, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="ACommand"  
            AutoCompleteMode="Append" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Modern" 
            Margin="280,405,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="330" 
            Height="30" 
            KeyDown="txtboxCommand_KeyDown"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

If you wanna get the selected item by the code-behind, convert the selected item to the Command class type.

```cs
var selectedItem = autoCompleteBox.SelectedItem as Command;
```

And actually there can be `multiple selected items`. In that case you have to define a `collection of Command objects`.

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Command> selectedCommands;

public ObservableCollection<Command> SelectedCommands
{
    get
    {
        return selectedCommands;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedCommands = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCommands");
    }
}
```

And bind it to the `SelectedItems` property (plural of SelectedItem) of the RadAutoCompleteBox control.

```
SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCommands, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

And make sure you have initiated the SelectedItems.

```cs
this.SelectedCommands = new ObservableCollection<Command>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, but when I bind `SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCommands, Mode=TwoWay}"` I get and exception of type `System.NotSupportedException` (`Collection was of fixed size.`).

Comment: I also get an error `Cannot resolve symbol 'NotifyPropertyChanged'`, so I deleted this line, hoping that it was no necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The `SearchText` property of the `RadAutoCompleteBox` should provide you the value.

According to the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/p_telerik_windows_controls_radautocompletebox_searchtext.html) it gets or sets the string that is into the TextBox part of the RadAutoCompleteBox. The SearchText value is used to filter the RadAutoCompleteBox' ItemsSource.

If you want to get the "Text" of the selected item of the AutocompleteBox, then you need to cast it to the specified type. In your case it is of type `ServerCrafterTelerikWPF.Command`.

```
var selectedItem = autoCompleteBox.SelectedItem;

if (selectedItem is ServerCrafterTelerikWPF.Command) {
  var selectedCommand = selectedItem as ServerCrafterTelerikWPF.Command;

  string textOfAutoCompleteBox = selectedCommand.ACommand;
}
```

Comment: That's the problem, there is no `Text` property.

Comment: `SearchText` only gets the string that used the **search** for an ItemSource. If an item has already been found and selected, that item is no longer in `SearchText`.

Comment: Thank you, nice and simple, but this only works when one item is selected.