# How to get 'Text' from the RadAutocomplete box and not the 'SearchText' when AutoComplete mode is 'SuggestAppend'?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am trying to get the text that get's appended in the Telerik Radautocompletebox when some value from dropdown is selected by keyboard down arrow key. The serchtext only gives the typed text but I need the whole text. How do I get this?

Comment: Did you try SelectedItem?

Answer (score 0):

For WPF - see [Get text of RadAutoCompleteBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894646/get-text-of-radautocompletebox)

For ASP.NET Web Forms -> Why not using the client-side OnClientEntryAdded(sender, eventArgs) event and eventArgs.get_entry().get_text() method as shown in this demo https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox/examples/programming/clientevents/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: The question is about WPF, not ASP.NET.